# Ajax Value into Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I want to the json data into the javascript variable so that whenever the database values changes I can do some operations according to the system logic. I am calling json from another `aspx` page.
The value in the json array will be either 1 or 0. I want this value in `value` variable in the javascript code shown below.
I am stuck here how can I get the data in the javascript variable.

I am not getting anything on the console as well.

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function requestData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'testjson.aspx',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (readData) {
                    console.log(readData);
                    var value = 1;
                    if (value == 1) {


                        var i = 1;
                        var msg1 = "Error.....Please Restart the system.";

                            var msgNo = "msg" + i;
                            msgNo = eval(msgNo);
                            var tgtLabel = document.getElementById("spnRandom");
                            tgtLabel.innerHTML = msgNo;


                    }
                },
                error: function (readData) {
                    console.log(readData);
                    var value = 1;
                    if (value == 1) {


                        var i = 1;
                        var msg1 = "Error.....Please Restart the system.";

                            var msgNo = "msg" + i;
                            msgNo = eval(msgNo);
                            var tgtLabel = document.getElementById("spnRandom");
                            tgtLabel.innerHTML = msgNo;

                    }
                },
            });

            window.onload = function () {
                window.setInterval(requestData, 1000);
            };
        };
    </script>
```

**JSON Code** Note this code is of the `testjson.aspx` which is called in the javascript.

```
public partial class Admin_testjson : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public string DATA;
    List<string> hidXCategories11 = new List<string>();

    public string chartData
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double ol1;
        GetData();
        var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var timeDiff = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        var totaltime = timeDiff.TotalMilliseconds;
        List<int> _data = new List<int>();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {

            ol1 = Convert.ToInt32(row["OLR1"]);
            _data.Add(ol1);
        }


        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        chartData = jss.Serialize(_data);
        Response.Write(chartData);

    }


    private void GetData()
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MCAS;Integrated Security=SSPI");
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 1 * from MCASMonitoring_Rev1 order by Id desc ", con);

        adp.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

**JSON View**

[1] or another case is [0] (It is the view when the page is open)

Comment: You should take a look at Knockout.js, it makes life much easier when it comes to fetching data and binding it to the frontend UI.

Comment: What can I do  in this particular case? I will definitely go for the Knockout.js in the next project.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Just assign what interests you from readData response.

Comment: thats the problem I dont know how to assing from ajax response.

Comment: Use console.log(readData) and post here what your response looks like.

Comment: It's showing nothing.

Comment: Since you are saying you are getting JSON View as [1] or [0]. Your json response (readData) is an array with one element in it. So you can assign value as `var value = readData[0];`

Comment: @RajuRudru: thanks for the reply but now the problem is that i am not getting on the console after using console.log. Please see the updated code for the same.

Comment: is your ASP code working fine? Looks like a problem with making a request to testjson.aspx to me.

Comment: yes asp code is perfect.

Comment: I got the reply... I have called the setinterval function in wrongly manner which was causing the problem.

Comment: Glad you found it. Edit your question and post your anwser for the others.